# After Connect to Access, String cannot join together

Tags: string, vb.net, ms-access

I use VB.net to create a program, the function is search data from Access, then save the data to html file.

But when after search data from Access, the string cannot join together.

```
    Dim strpath As String = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\output\\"
    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(strpath)) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(strpath)
    End If
    Dim strfilename As String = strpath + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss") + "_" + textBox_name.Text + ".html"

    Dim screach_name As String = textBox_name.Text
    Dim html_code As String = ""

    html_code += "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>"
    html_code += screach_name
    html_code += "</title></head><body>"
    html_code += "Screach:<b>" + screach_name + "</b><br />"
    Try

        Dim strcon As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=data.mdb;"
        Dim con_db As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(strcon)

        Dim sql_count As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table where name Like '%" + search_name + "%'"
        Dim com_data As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql_count, con_db)
        Dim count_data As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(com_data.ExecuteScalar())
        html_code += "Number of records = "
        html_code += count_data.ToString


    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally

    End Try
        html_code += "</body></html>"


    Using file As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(strfilename, True)
        file.WriteLine(html_code)
    End Using
```

But the html output only

> Blockquote

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>  <head>  <title>
screach_name
    </title>    </head> <body>
Screach:    <b>  screach_name   </b>    <br />
```

> Blockquote

Comment: Remove that useless Try/Catch/Finally. If something happens while you query the database you will never know. Show the Exception message at least (ex.Message)

Comment: By the way, it is pretty sure that something is wrong in your query. Notice how there is no text after the initial HTML? This is a strong hint that you got an exception and the code flows out of this method from the Finally part

Comment: Thank you! I have find the problem. I forget write 
"con_db.open" 
on after 
"Dim con_db As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(strcon)".

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 different things going on in your method. Your code would be easier to follow,  maintain, and test if you break it up into 3 different methods. Notice that the demonstrated methods are not connected to the user interface (no direct references to textBox_name.Text). This could come in handy if you restructure your app and move, for example, the GetRecordCount method to a DataAccess class.

The Using...End Using blocks in the GetRecordCount method ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error.

The StringBuilder in the BuildHTMLString method saves the program form creating and throwing away strings. Everytime you change a string in any way the program must throw away the old string and create an entirely new one.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim RecordCount = GetRecordCount(textBox_name.Text)
    Dim HTMLString = BuildHTMLString(RecordCount, textBox_name.Text)
    SaveHTMLString(HTMLString, textBox_name.Text)
End Sub

Private Function GetRecordCount(SearchName As String) As Integer
    Dim RecordCount As Integer
    'Pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=data.mdb;")
        'Pass the query text an the connection directly to the constructor of the command
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table where name Like @SearchName;", cn)
            'Always use parameters
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SearchName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" & SearchName & "%"
            RecordCount = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        End Using
    End Using
    Return RecordCount
End Function

Private Function BuildHTMLString(RecordCount As Integer, SearchName As String) As String
    Dim HTMLString As String = ""
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    sb.AppendLine("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>")
    sb.AppendLine(SearchName)
    sb.AppendLine("</title></head><body>")
    sb.AppendLine("Screach:<b>" & SearchName & "</b><br />")
    sb.AppendLine("Number of records = " & RecordCount.ToString)
    sb.AppendLine("</body></html>")
    HTMLString = sb.ToString
    Return HTMLString
End Function

Private Sub SaveHTMLString(HTML As String, SearchName As String)
    'Add Imports System.IO to the top or the file
    'Using Path.Combine makes sure the back slashes are OK
    Dim strpath As String = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "\output\")
    If (Not Directory.Exists(strpath)) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(strpath)
    End If
    Dim HTMLFileName As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss") & "_" & SearchName & ".html"
    Dim strfilename As String = Path.Combine(strpath, HTMLFileName)
    Using file As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(strfilename, True)
        file.WriteLine(HTML)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for you help!  This is my first time write the file IO program. I will try to use method to my program.